# How do I import an image into my React Native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to include an image in my app via:

```
function Interactions(props) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image source={require('./assets/comment_32.png')} />
            <Text>{props.info.replies}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

But I'm getting the following error - `TypeError: Failed to construct 'Image': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Comment: from where you are importing the `Image` ?

Comment: from my local filesystem

Comment: I meant the `<Image />` component, can provide the import statements?

Comment: You're right, I haven't imported the Image component!  Make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import the Image component from react-native.

```js
import { Image } from 'react-native';
```